# Bayes estimator for probability distribution with given prior density.

Tags: statistics, bayesian, parameter-estimation

I'm working on a mathematical statistics problem.

Let $X_{i},...,X_{n}$ be a sample from a probability distribution with density $p_{\theta}(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0$ elsewhere, with $\theta>0$ unknown.

Now I want to determine the Bayes estimator for $\theta$ with respect to prior density $\pi$ given by $\pi(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$ for $\theta>0$ and $0$ elsewhere.

So my understanding on how to tackle this problem goes so far: we first note that both densities line up with respect to their domains for $\theta$ and $x$, which makes them workable. Now we know that the Bayes estimator will be the expected value for the posterior function, which is given by $p_{\theta}(x) \pi(\theta)$. Thus, we will compete the posterior and then compute its expected value.

$p_{\theta}(x) \pi(\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1} e^{-\theta}$, which we can't really simplify. Thus we take its expected value and find

$E(p_{\theta}(x) \pi(\theta)) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta x_{i}^{\theta-1} e^{-\theta} = \frac{\theta e^{\theta}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{\theta-1}.$

But this solution doesn't site quite right to me, I expect to find a more intuitive expectant, one that is standard.

So where do I go wrong? Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348012/bayes-estimator-p-thetax-theta-x-theta-1-1-0-1x-and-pi-thet?rq=1

Comment: you're right, did not find that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to determine the Bayes estimator for $\theta$ with respect to prior density $\pi$ given by $\pi(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$ for $\theta>0$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Note that both densities line up with respect to their domains for $\theta$ and $x$, which makes them workable. Now we know that the Bayes estimator will be the expected value for the posterior function, which is given by $p_{\theta}(x) \pi(\theta)$. 
Thus, we will compete the posterior and then compute its expected value. I will not bother about the normalization of our posterior function, so I will leave that out of the computations.

First we will compute $\prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} p_{\theta}(x)$ and it follows that

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_{\theta}(x) &= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta X_{i}^{\theta-1}\\
        &= e^{\log \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta X_{i}^{\theta-1}}\\
        &= e^{\log \theta^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{\theta-1}}\\
        &= e^{\log \theta^{n}} e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\theta-1)\log X_{i}}\\
        &=\theta^{n} e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\theta-1)\log X_{i}}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Now we compute the posterior by multiplying the above by our prior density $\pi(\theta)$. We then have

\begin{equation}\label{eqgood}
    \begin{split}
        \theta^{n} e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\theta-1)\log X_{i}} e^{\theta} &= \theta^{n} e^{-\theta +\theta \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log X_{i} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log X_{i}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Which gives

\begin{equation}\label{eqbad}
    \begin{split}
        \theta^{n} e^{-\theta +\theta \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log X_{i} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log X_{i}} &= \theta^{n} e^{-\theta +\theta \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log X_{i}}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

From the above we can see that this is a gamma distribution with $\alpha= n+1$ and $\lambda=1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log (X_{i})$. Then the bayes estimator is the expected value, which for a gamma distribution is equal to $\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$, which gives $\frac{n+1}{\lambda=1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log (X_{i})}$.